# One localization source for code and design

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard

Is there any way to use just one file for localizing texts in Xcode 7 and above?
Maybe some kind of macro/script in Xcode.. whatever..?

I mean making the storyboard/IB resources to use the words directly from a Localizable.strings file instead of having the code using the texts from localizable and the storyboad having their own localization files.

Please share your opinions/solutions about that. Also please do not mention the solution of entering everything through code, that does not seem valid/recommended.

Comment: This should not matter since you should be exporting to an Xliff file when translating/sending to your translators–when this happens, all of your strings files will be put into one single Xliff file.

Comment: Tnx) didn't know) noobie me) Just for the beauty of the answer, can you provide the basic steps in a full answer bellow so I can accept it?

Comment: I have a strange problem when exporting.. it fails with error.. and from what I investigated (I also run the terminal command for exporting) it states that there is a character that cannot be encoded for xml and it's not really showing what character is causing the problem. Do you have any experience with this kind of error? I have the app base localization in estonian so there are some characters that are right only in utf-8. But there are too many of them in order to be able to check which one of them causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can consolidate your localisable content into a single file to send out for translation:

1. With your Xcode project open, select the project file
2. Editor -> Export for Localization...
3. Follow the steps

You will then get an .xliff file for each language that you want to have as part of your app. Send this out to your translators, and they will send it back, with the localised content. Once that's done, simply do the same steps, but for importing instead:

1. With your Xcode project open, select the project file
2. Editor -> Import Localizations...
3. Follow the steps